# Split string at space or "/" or after max character after certain number of characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I know a lot of similar questions have been asked and those have already helped me a lot but my problem now is that I don't know how to split the string either after a space OR a / or nothing if there is no space or / in it.

I'm currently working with some products description that needs to be printed and some are too long and need to be splitted. 
The problem is that no one has the same pattern, some has spaces or / or nothing and it needs to be splitted at spaces or / to be readable. 
so for the moment I got the following code:

```
var res = str.match(/.{1,10}(\s||[/])/g) ;
```

- for the following input : STEP-PS/1AC/24DC/2.5

I get the outputs : STEP-PS/1A and C/24DC/2.5

And would like to get: STEP-PS/1AC and /24DC/2.5 or STEP-PS/1AC/ and 24DC/2.5

- for the following input : AXL F DO16/3 XC 2F

I get the outputs : AXL F DO16 and /3 XC 2F and blank

And would like to get : AXL F DO16 and /3 XC 2F without the blank output

- And for the following input : ASDFDDCL21EDFG

I get the correct output : ASDFDDCL21 and EDFG

What should I change to get the good outputs and is it even possible ? 
(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
.{1,10}(?:[^\s\/]+?[\s\/])?
```

[image]

```js
const regex = /.{1,10}(?:[^\s\/]+?[\s\/])?/g;
const strs = ["STEP-PS/1AC/24DC/2.5", "AXL F DO16/3 XC 2F", "ASDFDDCL21EDFG"]

strs.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str.match(regex))
})
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/DO9Wt7/1/)

Comment: How'd you make that pretty picture?

Comment: its working for the first output problem. Instead of getting STEP-PS/1A and C/24DC/2.5 I now get STEP-PS/1AC/ and 24DC/2.5 . That's perfect 
This code wordked, just don't forget to add "/g" or he will stop after the first match
```javascript 
match(/.{1,10}(?:[^\s\/]+?[\s\/])?/g)
```

Now the problem is that for the second output problem i still get a blank output.

Comment: @LukaAUDE i have added a snippet to show what output it will return, i am not understanding what do you mean by getting empty output ? can you elaborate

Comment: Its my bad, I don't know why i added spaces at the end of my input like that : "AXL F DO16/3 XC 2F    " so I was getting a third output with this spaces. Now its all good and working fine, thanks a lot and have a great day

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() along with join() as below based on your requirement in JavaScript.

```
var test ="STEP-PS/1AC/24DC/2.5 hh kk ll";
var res = test.split('/').join('/ ').split(' ').join(' ');
$('#msg').html(res)
```

Try it on,
https://playcode.io/

In case you need any specific help. Please let me know.
Thanks,

Comment: Thanks but it kinda worked with work with the following code ```javascript var res = str.match(/.{1,10}(?:[^\s\/]+?[\s\/])?/g) ; ```
I tested your code but i can't define the max size of the outputs like with match with ```javascript {1,10} ```